# PHP is not recognizing my '<del>' tag in index.view.php and removing it from the outputted html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make the PHP code in my index.view.php file put a strike through the task description if completed is true. I have been following a tutorial on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/12?autoplay=true) introducing me to classes and he uses `<strike></strike>`, however that didn't work and I saw on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strike.asp) that HTML5 doesn't support that tag anymore and was advised to use `<s></s>` or `<del></del>` instead. This, however, didn't work for me.

I have tried using Firefox instead of Google Chrome, however, the output was exactly the same. The problem still persisted.

The following is my index.php file:

```
<?php

class Task {
      public $description;
      public $completed = false;

      public function __construct($description)
      {
        $this->description = $description;
      }

      public function complete()
      {
        $this->$completed = true;
      }

      public function isComplete()
      {
        return $this->$completed;
      }
    }

    $tasks = [
      new Task("Go to the store"),
      new Task("Finish my screencast"),
      new Task("Finish PHP Course")
    ];

    $tasks[0] -> complete();

    require 'index.view.php';
```

The following is my index.view.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>

        <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>

        <li>

            <?php if ($task->completed) : ?>
              <del><?= $task->description; ?></del>
            <?php else: ?>
              <?= $task->description; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following is the HTML that gets outputted on Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>


        <li>

                          Go to the store            
        </li>


        <li>

                          Finish my screencast            
        </li>


        <li>

                          Finish PHP Course            
        </li>


    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer is `$task->completed` is not `true` for any of those `$tasks`. PHP wont arbitrarily remove HTML from the output unless instructed to.

Comment: Voting to class as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo: `$this->$completed = true;` has an additional dollar in it and should be `$this->completed = true;` (this was reasonably obvious after `print_r($tasks);`

Comment: Thanks, in my class I wrote  return $this->$completed; when it should have been  return $this->completed;.

Comment: On the plus-side though, this was actually a well-written question even if the solution was just a simple typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get and set methods are wrong. You have a dollar sign too much. This is what you should do.

```
public function complete() { 
    $this->completed = true; 
} 

public function isComplete() {
    return $this->completed; 
}
```

Also, a tip: Try to use the `isComplete()` getter instead of accessing the `completed` property if you write a getter. Then you also can make the property private.